# How to set lager.error_logger_hwm in RabbitMQ by rabbitmqctl command

Tags: docker, logging, rabbitmq, erlang, lager

This [How to set error_logger_hwm in the new RabbitMQ .conf configuration file format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770198/how-to-set-error-logger-hwm-in-the-new-rabbitmq-conf-configuration-file-format) not suitable for my situation which running `rabbitmq`(**RabbitMQ 3.7.10 on Erlang 20.2.2 -- Ubuntu 16.04**) by docker container.

I could add **advanced.config** in the host's directory, and update **config.json** for generating **/var/lib/rabbitmq/config/generated/rabbitmq.config** automatically after restart it.

```
root@*-pc:/etc/kolla/rabbitmq# cat advanced.config 
[
    {lager, [
        {error_logger_hwm, 4000}
    ]}
].

root@*-pc:/etc/kolla/rabbitmq# cat config.json 
{
    "command": "/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server",
    "config_files": [
        {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/advanced.config",
            "dest": "/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config",
            "owner": "rabbitmq",
            "perm": "0600"
        },
        {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/rabbitmq.conf",
            "dest": "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf",
            "owner": "rabbitmq",
            "perm": "0600"
        },
        ......

root@*-pc:/etc/kolla/rabbitmq# docker restart  rabbitmq 
rabbitmq
root@*-pc:/etc/kolla/rabbitmq# docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_env(lager, error_logger_hwm).'
{ok,4000}
```

Question:

- Is there any command to **set the environment** parameter such as `'application:get_env(lager, error_logger_hwm).'` for **get the environment** parameter. Also can't find any clue at [rabbitmq configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#verify-configuration-effective-configuration).

```
# docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl eval '[lager:set_loghwm(error_logger_hwm, 4000)]'
Error (argument validation): "syntax error before: "
Arguments given:
    eval [lager:set_loghwm(error_logger_hwm, 4000)]

Usage:
rabbitmqctl [-n <node>] [-l] [-q] eval <expr>
```

**It also seems doesn't raise the limit, I don't know what's that meaning.** Reference from [RabbitMQ lager_error_logger_h dropped messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552879/rabbitmq-lager-error-logger-h-dropped-messages).

```
# docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_env(lager, error_logger_hwm).'
{ok,50}

# docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl eval '[lager:set_loghwm(H, 4000) || H <- gen_event:which_handlers(lager_event)].'
[{last_loghwm,50},ok]

# docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_env(lager, error_logger_hwm).'
{ok,50}

# docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl eval '[lager:set_loghwm(H, 4000) || H <- gen_event:which_handlers(lager_event)].'
[{last_loghwm,4000},ok]

# docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_env(lager, error_logger_hwm).'
{ok,50}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl eval 'application:set_env(lager,error_logger_hwm,4000).'
```

Maybe it works.
https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/application.html#set_env-2

```
lager:set_loghwm(error_logger_hwm, 4000)]
```

The above code does not work because `lager` application doesn't start and `lager`'s function can't be called. https://hexdocs.pm/lager/lager.html#set_loghwm-2

Comment: THX, I will try. What will be effected after setting the big value? In lager **README.md** says about `error_logger_hwm`: It is probably best to keep this number small.

Comment: ``lager`` is used to log, it communicate with os's io. The more log to write down, the system's response speed is lower. Therefore  when ``hwm`` 's changed to small level, the speed can be quicker.

Comment: It doesn't work:`Error:
{:undef, [{:application, :set_env, [:lager, [error_logger_hwm: 4000]], []}, {:erl_eval, :do_apply, 6, [file: 'erl_eval.erl', line: 670]}, {:rpc, :"-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-", 5, [file: 'rpc.erl', line: 197]}]}`

Comment: docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl eval 'application:set_env(lager,error_logger_hwm,4000).'